# Extracting hours from a DateTime (SQL Server 2005)

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2005, hour

I can extract the month and day by using `Day(Date())`, `Month(Date())`. I can't extract hours, with `HOUR(Date())`. I get the following error.

```
'HOUR' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

How can I extract hours?

Comment: I find this useful: SELECT FORMAT(getdate(), 'hh:mm:ss', 'en-US') 'Time'

Answer (score 483, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE());
```

[`DATEPART` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420%28loband%29.aspx)

Comment: Please spell out things like `HOUR` instead of using lazy shorthand that isn't always what you expect (try `y`). Feel free to maintain your own code however you like, but for teaching, I am opposed to ***promoting*** lazy shorthand that leads to confusion or worse. See #6 here http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-wrong-optimizations/ and https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx

Comment: @AaronBertrand That's not "lazy shorthand", it's the documented short-form. "Lazy" is using short-forms that are shorter than the minimal documented version, which may work but may have unintended consequences.

Comment: @Auspex Can’t force you to not completely miss the point or to read the reasons behind my words. Not everything that’s documented is a best practice.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I got the point. But you're trying to enforce (to the extent of improperly editing _multiple_ people's answers) your own standards. Your "best practice" is nothing of the sort.

Answer (score 48):

... you can use it on any granularity type i.e.:

```
DATEPART(YEAR, [date])

DATEPART(MONTH, [date]) 

DATEPART(DAY, [date])    

DATEPART(HOUR, [date]) 

DATEPART(MINUTE, [date])
```

(note: I like the [ ] around the date reserved word though. Of course that's in case your column with timestamp is labeled "date")

Answer (score 23):

Use [datepart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx).

E.g.:

```
datepart(hh, date)
```

Answer (score 10):

try this one too:

```
   DATEPART(HOUR,GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 9):

The DATEPART() function is used to return a single part of a date/time, such as year, month, day, hour, minute, etc.

```
datepart    ***Abbreviation

year        ***yy, yyyy 
quarter     ***qq, q 
month       ***mm, m 
dayofyear   ***dy, y 
day         ***dd, d 
week        ***wk, ww 
weekday     ***dw, w 
hour        ***hh 
minute      ***mi, n 
second      ***ss, s 
millisecond ***ms 
microsecond ***mcs 
nanosecond  ***ns
```

Example

```
select * 
from table001
where datepart(hh,datetime) like 23
```

Answer (score 6):

`DATEPART(HOUR, [date])` returns the hour in military time ( 00 to 23 )
If you want 1AM, 3PM etc, you need to case it out:

```
SELECT Run_Time_Hour =
CASE DATEPART(HOUR, R.date_schedule)
    WHEN 0 THEN  '12AM'
    WHEN 1 THEN   '1AM'
    WHEN 2 THEN   '2AM'
    WHEN 3 THEN   '3AM'
    WHEN 4 THEN   '4AM'
    WHEN 5 THEN   '5AM'
    WHEN 6 THEN   '6AM'
    WHEN 7 THEN   '7AM'
    WHEN 8 THEN   '8AM'
    WHEN 9 THEN   '9AM'
    WHEN 10 THEN '10AM'
    WHEN 11 THEN '11AM'
    WHEN 12 THEN '12PM'
    ELSE CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(HOUR, R.date_schedule)-12) + 'PM'
END
FROM
    dbo.ARCHIVE_RUN_SCHEDULE R
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this one too:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(8),GETDATE(),108)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select case when [am or _pm] ='PM' and datepart(HOUR,time_received)<>12 
           then dateadd(hour,12,time_received) 
           else time_received 
       END 
from table
```

works

Answer (score 0):

> I can't extract hours, with HOUR(Date())

There is a way to call `HOUR` (I would not recommend to use it though because there is `DATEPART` function) using [ODBC Scalar Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/odbc-scalar-functions-transact-sql):

```
SELECT {fn HOUR(GETDATE())} AS hour
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/BTRMC86088)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

To include AM / PM - use the below:

```
SELECT 
  concat(case when datepart(hour,getdate()) % 12 = 0 then 12 
              else datepart(hour,getdate()) % 12 end,
         case when datepart(hour,getdate()) < 12 then ' AM' 
              else ' PM' end
        )
```

Answer (score -3):

you must use datepart()

```
like 


datepart(hour , getdate())
```

Comment: What's the point of your contribution, which repeats information provided in almost every other "answer" to this question?

Answer (score -3):

```
select convert(time,GETDATE())
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it