# SQL DateTime Data

Tags: c#, sql

I have a SQL table like below.

```
SELECT * FROM [icom].[dbo].[Periods]
```

This table gives me periods that I specified. For example period one starts at 8:00 and ends at 8:45am.

When I run the query, it gives me date and time milliseconds format. So how could I get only time? Like 8:00am?

Comment: Try using `DATEPART` in SQL to get the time in the format you need.

Comment: I suggest that you use the value you get from the database as it is and then do all "formatting" in your application. You will be more flexible if you don't do the processing at database level. If you do so, you'll get back a string. Otherwise you'll have a `DateTime` which you can convert and use as you wish.

Comment: How could I format value in c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using SQL Server (which I think you are), it sounds like you're using the `datetime` data type:

`datetime` represents an instant in time. Internally, `datetime` consists of a pair of integers:

- The first measures the offset in days from the *epoch*. An epoch is the zero point of a calendar system, which for SQL Server `1 January 1900 00:00:00.000`.
- The second is the [positive] offset since start of day, in milliseconds.

How that internal representation is represented *visually* is entirely up to you, though SQL Server has a [configurable] default conversion pattern.

If you are accessing your SQL programmatically, say from C#, the API automatically maps the SQL Server `datetime` datatype to your languages equivalent type (`System.Datetime` for C#). The issue is present: it is your responsibility to format it visually or textually.

If you want to see only the date component. You can format it in T-SQL using the `convert()`/`cast()` function: `convert(varchar(32),{some-datetime-expression},116)` will convert the `{some-datetime-expression}` to the format `dd mmm yyyy`. Lots of other options.

Further assuming that you are using a recent-ish version of SQL Server, if you just want to deal with dates, change your schema to use the `date` datatype instead of `datetime`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a CONVERT command in your query. Like so:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 108) * FROM [icom].[dbo].[Periods]
```

For more formats and examples you can check out: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx  I hope that helps!

Comment: Also there is a "Time" data type in SQL 2008 and beyond. Using that may be easier, but I'm not sure for your specific circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `SELECT DATEPART(hh, [YourDatetimeColumn]) FROM [Periods]`. You might also find useful answers by taking a look at [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114307/extracting-hours-from-a-datetime-sql-server-2005).