# convert time portion of date to an int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column called `enteredindate` that includes data such as:

```
2012-10-10 18:02:00
2012-10-11 13:30:00
2012-10-11 14:27:00
2012-10-12 14:14:00
```

How do I make a new column that has an `INT` data value next to this `enteredindate`column like this?

```
1802
1330
1427
1414
```

Comment: (Parse out the Hour) * 100 + Minute [DatePart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Comment: So, as @AdamWenger said: `DATEPART(HOUR,enteredindate)*100+DATEPART(MINUTE,enteredindate)`

Comment: The [Extracting hours from a DateTime (SQL Server 2005)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1114307/335858) question suggested as a duplicate is not a good candidate, because it answers only part of the question (although it does give a good idea on how to proceed). The second part, namely, how to combine the hours and minutes, is not answered in the duplicate. I am voting to re-open this question (but please comment if you find a better duplicate, I'll gladly vote to close the question back).

Answer (score 2):

Use [`datepart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx):

```
select datepart(hour, enteredindate) * 100
       + datepart(minute, enteredindate)
```

Comment: @Hong: need more help?

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the desited number using this expression:

```
DATEPART(hour,d) * 100 + DATEPART(minute,d)
```

where `d` is the name of your `datetime` column.

Multiply hours by `100` before adding minutes to treat them as the first two digits of a four-digit number.

[Demo.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/92f43/3)