# Get current hour

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
select GETDATE() as currentDate
```

returns

> 2016-01-18 10:54:31.780

How can I do that it return

> 2016-01-18 10:00:00

according [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx) `GETDATE()` has no parameterized constructor

Comment: Possible duplidate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114307/extracting-hours-from-a-datetime-sql-server-2005

Comment: select datepart(hour, getdate())

Comment: `SELECT
 GETDATE(),
 DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0 , GETDATE()), 0)`

Comment: select dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, GETDATE()), 0)

Comment: @FelixPamittan that's exactly what i needed

Comment: If you looking for current hour i think you can use this sample SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),getdate(),108) ;

Answer (score 4):

Try like this,

```
SELECT FORMAT(getdate(), 'yyyy-MM-dd:HH:00:00') as DateAndHour
```