# Converting hhmmss to int (HH to int)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column with `HHMMSS` in a table.

Similar to this out put:

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 108)
```

I need to be able to make a view in MSSMS with only the HH from time and convert it as an int.

Example
Time

```
11:08:11, 
12:08:12
Int
11
,12
```

I have tried several tricks from this page but could not find any work around
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/

Comment: Please have a look into the thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114307/extracting-hours-from-a-datetime-sql-server-2005

Comment: I am confused, what is "Example Time" here, and how the accepted answer handling the sample example time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use `DATEPART`? There's no need to convert the value from a `datetime` to a `varchar` and then to an `int`.

```
SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE());
```

*Edit: on a different note, I strongly suggest you always ensure you declare your length, precision and scale when using a datatype. `SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 108)` will return the whole value here, as (in this case) this it converts the value to a `varchar(25)`, however, not declaring these parameters can/does leads to unexpected behaviour.*

*I've seen many questions where people have asked "Why isn't this working?" because their SP is declared as `CREATE PROC MyProc @String varchar AS ...`, or they have a variable declaration of `DECLARE @MyVar nvarchar;`, which in both cases means the length has a value of 1; and thus their values are truncated.*

*Edit for Irony: And no less than an hour later... [Substring function not comparing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54346155/substring-function-not-comparing-the-output); looks like I need to order a new crystal ball. Exactly why not declaring your Length, Precision or Scale is a bad idea.*

Answer (score 1):

One way could be this:

```
SELECT   LEFT(convert(varchar, getdate(), 108),2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stuff()` & do conversations :

```
select col, datepart(hh, cast(stuff(stuff(col, 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':') as time(0)))
from table t;
```

This assumes `col` has `varchar` type time.