# How can I extract just the time component from an Oracle timestamp value?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I'm attempting to create a breakdown of requests per hour. As such the date part of the TimeStamp object needs to be ignored. This is what I've tried to far:

```
select 
    trunc(request_time, 'HH'),
    count(*)
    
from 
    service_request

group by
    trunc(request_time, 'HH');
```

This seems to group all data into one hour sections but also groups by the day. How do I go about removing the date part so I end up with results like:

```
Time     Count
--------------
00:00        1
01:00        4
02:00        2
```

Comment: Oracle does not have a `DATETIME` data type. Did you mean `DATE` (which, in Oracle) does have a time component?

Comment: May [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1114314/9183949) help you to extract hours

Comment: The datatype is actually TIMESTAMP, it's been a long morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do

```
select to_number( to_char( request_time, 'HH24' ) ),
       count(*)
  from service_request
 group by to_number( to_char( request_time, 'HH24' ) );
```

The `to_number` is probably not strictly necessary but it makes more sense to return a numeric hour than a string hour for things like sorting.

If the data type is actually a timestamp, then you could improve this

```
select extract( hour from request_time ),
       count(*)
  from service_request
 group by extract( hour from request_time );
```

Comment: Thank you very much this worked perfectly. I'll go have a look at the to_char function.

Comment: @Cyreaver - Since you updated your question to say it was actually a timestamp, I updated my answer to use the `extract` function instead.  That's likely to be a cleaner approach.

Comment: Thanks again, that is much cleaner to read. Is there any way to have the hour displayed as 00:00 / 01:00 instead of 0/1?

Comment: @Cyreaver - If you want a string, you could use `to_char( trunc(request_time,'HH'), 'HH24:MI' )`.