# WHERE datetime is 08:00 in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a following problem. I have this table:

```sql
day | valueA | valueB
2022-04-24 04:35:08 2929 | 5845
2022-04-24 06:30:10 2929 | 5844
2022-04-24 07:25:12 2929 | 5844
2022-04-24 08:00:12 2929 | 7844
2022-04-24 12:15:10 2929 | 5844
2022-04-24 14:10:09 2929 | 5844
```

I would like to get `valueB - valueA` only if it is `8:00`. So from the example above I would get 4915, because 7844-2929.

I tried this based on this answer, which is however about MSSQL: [Extracting hours from a DateTime (SQL Server 2005)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114307/extracting-hours-from-a-datetime-sql-server-2005) but it does not work:

```
SELECT valueB - valueA AS diff
FROM table
WHERE day(HOUR, GETDATE()) = 8
```

I got that `MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1305, 'FUNCTION table.day does not exist')`. How can I do this in MySQL, please?

Comment: Well you're using mysql, the question you linked is about MSSQL Server and you just copied something from the question

Comment: Please refer to manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT valueB - valueA AS diff
FROM table
WHERE HOUR(day) = 8
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in 8:00 you also need to check for the minutes

```
SELECT valueB - valueA AS diff
FROM table
WHERE HOUR(day) = 8 AND MINUTE(day) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work:

```
SELECT valueB - valueA AS diff
FROM table
WHERE HOUR(day) = 8
```